# Prove that this trace ratio problem is well defined and have a maximum

Tags: linear-algebra, data-analysis

Given a symmetric matrix A, of dimension n×n and an arbitrary unitary matrix V of dimension n×p.
we define the trace ratio problem
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\max _{V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}} & \frac{\operatorname{Tr}\left[V^{T} A V\right]}{\operatorname{Tr}\left[V^{T} B V\right]} \\
V^{T} C V=I
\end{array}\right.
$$
where B and C are assumed to be symmetric and positive definite.

I want to show that it exists  a maximum for this problem?
I know that is sufficient to prove that the  function $f(V)=\frac{\operatorname{Tr}\left[V^{T} A V\right]}{\operatorname{Tr}\left[V^{T} B V\right]}$ is a continuous function over  the  closed set of matrices V satisfying $V^T CV $.

My question is how to prove that the set above is a closed set?

Comment: If $V_n \to V$ and $V_n^TCV_n = I$ for all $n$, then $I = V_n^TCV_n \to V^TCV$. Hence the set of matrices V satisfying $V^TCV = I$ is closed.

Comment: (1) $V$ is not unitary (which implies invertibility).  It is in general a real matrix with mutually orthonormal columns.  (2) Note, not all PD $C$'s work here (though the set is trivially closed if it's empty).  Another approach is to look at the complement i.e. $U^T C U = Z \neq I$.  Then $Z$ has at least one eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 1$.  Then for any matrix with orthonormal columns in a sufficiently close $\delta$ neighborhood to $U$, you can use topological eigenvalue continuity...